# Destroying an entry using cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I have a Ruby on Rails application in which I'm writing a CRUD test suite for all of my pages.

The first three CRUD actions - Create, Retrieve, and Update I can do no problem.

What I'm having trouble with is the last one - Destroy - since I need to start from the index page of whatever model I'm testing, and all of the links have the same "Destroy" text.  If I just follow "Destroy" I get an ambiguous match.

I realize this is probably pretty simple - but I'm new to cucumber and capybara.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are listing the elements in a table then you can select a specific element with specific text (for example, if you are testing deletion for users then you can select a table row which has the user fullname as the text.

Something like this:

```
When /^I click the 'Delete' button for the "([^"]*) user $/ do |value|
  within(".users") do
    page.find("tr", :text => value).click_link "Delete"
  end 
end
```

Comment: You're welcome! if the solution worked for you then Could you mark the question as answered? Thanks!